# How do I get a user's friendly username on UNIX?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to get the "friendly" name, not the username, at least if such a string exists for the given user. Things I've tried:

```
whoami
jamesarosen

id -un
jamesarosen

id -p
uid jamesarosen
groups  staff com.apple.access_screensharing ...

id -P
jamesarosen:********:501:20::0:0:James A. Rosen:/Users/jamesarosen:/bin/bash
```

That last one has the information I'm looking for, but I'd prefer not to have to parse it out, particularly since I'm not terribly confident that the format (specifically the number of `:`s) will remain consistent across OSes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Parse the GECOS Field for User's Full Name

The format of /etc/passwd and most of the [GECOS field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) is extremely well standardized across Unix-like systems. If you find an exception, by all means let us know. Meanwhile, the easiest way to get what you want on a Unix-like system is to use *getent* and *cut* to parse the GECOS field. For example:

```
getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1
```

Comment: Please note that `getent` is not in POSIX. Macs, for example, don’t have it.

Comment: Based on this and Ansgar Wiechers's answer below, works on both MacOs Sierra and CentOS: `finger $LOGNAME | head -1 | awk -F': ' '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I know would be to parse it:

```
grep -P "^$(whoami):" /etc/passwd | cut -f5 -d:
```

You can be pretty certain of the format of /etc/passwd

Comment: Note that not all systems have all accounts in an actual `/etc/passwd` file; some use other methods like LDAP or NIS. The `getent` command, if you have it, should work regardless of how entries are stored.

Comment: Perl's built-in `getpwnam` and related functions should also work correctly regardless of where the system stores its passwords (assuming it's on a POSIX-like system).

Comment: Also, please note that `whoami` is not in POSIX. You can use `id -un` instead, which does the same thing.

Comment: May I recommend changing that line to `grep -P "^$(whoami):" /etc/passwd | cut -f5 -d: | cut -f1 -d,` to remove the fields that are not the user's full name?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `finger` to obtain that information:

```
finger `id -un` | head -1 | cut -d: -f3-
```

which has the advantage (or disadvantage, depending on your requirements) that it will retrieve the information for non-local users as well.

If you only want to get the information from `/etc/passwd`, you'll most likely have to parse the file one way or the other, as others have already mentioned. Personally I'd prefer `awk` for this task:

```
awk -F: -vid=`id -u` '{if ($3 == id) print $5}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `/etc/passwd` file. This file shows you how user information is stored. Your user information may or  may not be stored here (There are several different databases that Unix uses for storing users), but the format is the same.

Basically, Unix uses the User ID (UID) to store what user is what. The next entry was the old password entry, then the UID, the primary Group ID, the [GECOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) field, the `$HOME` directory, and the user's shell. (There are three extra entries displayed in the `id -P` command in MacOS. I don't know what they are, but they make the GECOS field the eighth field instead of the fifth field).

Using the `id -P` command on your system gave you this entry. Some systems use `getent` or even `getpwent` as a command. What you need to do is parse this entry. Each field is separated by colons, so you need either the fifth or eighth the entry (depending upon the command you had to use).

The `awk` and `cut` commands do this quite nicely. `cut` is probably more efficient, but `awk` is more common, so I tend to use that.

In `awk`, the standard field separator is *white space*, but you can use the `-F` parameter to change this. In Awk, each field in a line is given a number and preceded by a dollar sign. The `$0` field is the entire line.

Using `awk`, you get:

```
id -P | awk -F: '{print $8}'
```

This says to take the `id -P` command, and use the `:` as a field separator, and to print out the eighth field. THe curly braces surround all *AWK programs*, and the single quotes are needed to keep the shell from interpreting the `$8`.

In BASH, you can use `$( )` to run a command and return it's output, so you can set environment variables:

```
$USER_NAME=$(id -P | awk -F: `{print $8}`)
echo $USER_NAME
```

Comment: Since the OP seemed concerned about portability: `id -P` won't work cross-platform. The option seems to be available on OS X and FreeBSD, but not on OpenBSD, AIX, and various Linux flavors. On HP-UX the option exists, but has a different meaning.

Comment: I mentioned this offhand. (Some systems use getenv and others getpwent). The `id -P` is POSIX, but Linux, and most BSD systems aren't 100% POSIX. The Mac doesn't have `getent` or `getpwent`. I was thinking of `finger` or `who`, but those implementations vary among machines too. The best you can do is try each and check the results. If the command doesn't return zero, try another variant.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS at least (and probably other *BSD-alikes), you may use: `id -F` to get just the full name.